# docker + traefik: how to route to different containers based on host name?

Tags: docker, traefik

Simple situation

- an nginx container, running internally on port 80, exposed to 9000
- an apache container, running internally on port 80, exposed to 9001

I added entry to my hosts file

- 127.0.0.1 nginx.test apache.test

My `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.rule=Host(`nginx.test`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.nginx.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
    ports:
      - "9000:80"

  apache:
    image: httpd
    container_name: apache
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.apache.rule=Host(`apache.test`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.apache.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
    ports:
      - "9001:80"

  proxy:
    image: "traefik:v2.5"
    container_name: "proxy"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
    depends_on:
      - nginx
      - apache
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./proxy.sock:/var/run/proxy.sock:ro
```

**What works is**

- I can see default nginx page for nginx at http://nginx.test:9000
- I can see default page for nginx at http://apache.test:9001

**What doesn't works and it's what I need*

- I want to access nginx at http://nginx.test
- I want to access nginx at http://apache.test

> please note: it's my first try with traefik. If it need some config, please help me

**Inspecting traefik container, I see this in logs**

```
2024-03-07 10:43:45 time="2024-03-07T09:43:45Z" level=error msg="Provider connection error Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?, retrying in 7.029037918s" providerName=docker
2024-03-07 10:43:52 time="2024-03-07T09:43:52Z" level=debug msg="FIXME: Got an status-code for which error does not match any expected type!!!: -1" module=api status_code=-1
2024-03-07 10:43:52 time="2024-03-07T09:43:52Z" level=error msg="Failed to retrieve information of the docker client and server host: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?" providerName=docker
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem.

All was about

```
volumes:
  - ./proxy.sock:/var/run/proxy.sock:ro
```

I fixed pointing to docker.sock on WSL2, becase I'm running docker under wsl2 on windows 11

Also, the destination path should point to docker.so and not proxy.sock

This works

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```